# How do I use a .NET .DLL file or library in VB6?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6, interop

I'm just wondering if there is something I should know of when doing this or will it work straight out of the bat as long as the .NET framework is installed on the client?

I ask because when I attempted this, VB6's references dialog said "cant register that dll"

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the other answers, .NET DLLS, even when they expose COM objects for use, as described in the other answers, DO NOT CONTAIN an embedded typelib so you unfortunately can't use what you're used to when dealing with COM libraries, RegSvr32.exe.

As Anivas pointed out, you have to use RegAsm.exe to register the .net assembly (the dll), and then VB6 should be able to see it (Add a reference to it in your VB6 project, the use the object browser to check what objects have been exposed).

Comment: thank you, so is regasm just the .net version of regsvr32 which registers .dll's for windows wide recognition (or for GAC) or is it just a process which creates a typelib that VB6 can understand for the .net .dll in question? thanks Dr. :) (upvoted)

Comment: No problem. Regasm actually does register the DLL's COM interfaces and such in the registry so that other COM apps can make use of it. The VS compiler generates the TLB file and other interop files when you compile your app IF you have the COM options checked on the compile screen in visual studio

Answer (score 7):

There is a project setting "Make assembly COM-Visible" in the "Assembly Information" section. Make sure you tick it.

Comment: FYI - adam nathan's book is the bible on this topic

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert that to a COM dll. Regasm the dll and use it.Use comvisible attribute.

Answer (score 1):

A little other information that might be useful: a .Net DLL isn't compiled code, it's written in "Intermediate Language" (IL).  You may find it interesting to open a .Net DLL with any text editor and look at it.

Comment: I realize that it's been a while since I answered this, but since then I've run across this from Mike Strong:  You can see all the .NET  System classes that are exposed as (late binding) ActiveX objects starting in the registry at  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\System.AccessViolationException through to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\System.Version

Once you've found something you might be interested in you can look it up in MSDN.
 Could be worth looking into.

Comment: thanks mate, useful information for sure! and just to add, i ALWAYS look at old posts just to see if there is any new information/comments added to them lol, and even to sometimes add additional things to them myself. sorry to throw u under the bus with me, but i think this upgrades us to the uber-geek grade (lol), and i think there should be badges for "old-post trollers", perhaps called exactly that :).